# PySNMP gets data but ends with timeout

Tags: python, pysnmp

I want to get data from my local router and I use pySnmp for it. I did it like this:

```
g = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
             CommunityData('public'),
             UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.7.1', 161)),
             ContextData(),
             ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)))
data = next(g)
```

After that I got a huge amount of printed data on the screen, but when I look into my **data** variable I got:

```
(<pysnmp.proto.errind.RequestTimedOut at 0x105b6bfd0>, 0, 0, [])
```

But I saw all the data I needed in the printed data, how can I solve that problem?

Comment: Have you tried playing with the UDP timeout? Like UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.7.1', 161), timeout=5, retries=0)

Comment: I wonder what kind of data you get on screen? For sysDescr.0 it should be just a single (usually short) string. Could it be debugging output?

Comment: Yes, it looks like some debugging info. I've tried to play with timeouts and retries but still get the same result - RequestTimedOut.

Comment: It looks like SNMP was disabled on the router side. When I turned it on everything started to work ))))

Comment: Good! Just keep in mind that by default pysnmp does not produce any debugging. You have to enable it explicitly.

Comment: I will )) Thanks one more time for your help!!!